# What's wrong with this code while writing or reading object on text file?

Tags: file, stream, streamreader

I want to write object on text file. Below is the code. Can anyone helps to find out the error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace TestObjectWritingInTextfile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test("Salma Mushtaq","61488");
            List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
            list.Add(t);
            FileStream file1 = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Files\testing.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file1);
            sw.WriteLine(t); // Here I want to write object
            FileStream file2 = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\Files\testing.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file2);
            List<Test> l = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public string name; 
        public string phone;
        public Test(string n, string p) {
            this.name = n;
            this.phone = p;
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to read object from text file, It shows unexpected errors.

Comment: What errors does "it" show?

Comment: Sami, When I see the file the text prints: Namespace.Filename. And when I read the object it shows:Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestObjectWritingInTextfile.Test>' C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\DOT NET\Projects\TestObjectWritingInTextfile\TestObjectWritingInTextfile\Program.cs 22 28 TestObjectWritingInTextfile

Comment: I also try: List<Test> l = (List<Test>) sr.ReadLine();

Comment: You cannot write objects as strings and then convert strings back to objects. You need some kind of serialization.

Comment: Can you please explain with some example? I am new in programming.

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and search for .net serialization, it will come up with many examples. It is way too broad subject to handle in an answer.